# Repeating alarm and time changes

Tags: android

I have set an alarm in my app which was working perfectly till previous week. The code i used was this

am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, setalarmon.getTimeInMillis(), 7000 * 3600 * 24, pi);

It sets an alarm for every Friday at 11:00 local time. The problem is that my country moved to other timezone cause of DST. We were at UTC+1 now we are at UTC+2 so alarm is now firing at 12:00.
Any idea on how to set the alarm firing at same time no matter that DST changes?

Answer (score 0):

I dont know exactly what *setalarmon* is. I guess its a calendar-object. The question is how did you define it?

`Calendar setalarmon = Calendar.getInstance(Locale.getDefault());`

should give you the right timezone.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is the calendar object and uses the correct local time. My problem is setRepeating is using UTC time. Here is what happened. Alarmed fired Friday 25 March at 11:00 correctly. It should fire again at Friday 1 April 11:00 so it is correctly set to repeat after 7*24*60*60*1000 milliseconds. The problem is local time changed due to DST and after these milliseconds local time is 12 not 11 so alarm is firing at 12. That's what i want to avoid and i am asking for help

Answer (score 0):

Try this: Here is my sample code

MainActivity:

```
public static int NOW_NOTIFICATION = 101; 

Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, NotificationReceiver.class);
                intent.putExtra(NotificationReceiver.NOTIFICATION_MESSAGE, "Sample Alert");
                PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
                        MainActivity.this, NOW_NOTIFICATION, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

                cancelNotification(NOW_NOTIFICATION);
                AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
                alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis()
                        + (2 * 1000), pendingIntent);
```

Cancel Notification:

```
public void cancelNotification(int requestCode) {
        try {
            Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), NotificationReceiver.class);
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), requestCode, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
            AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
            alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

NotificationReceiver:

```
public class NotificationReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    public static String NOTIFICATION_MESSAGE = "notificationMessage";


    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String message = intent.getStringExtra(NOTIFICATION_MESSAGE);
        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        //Define sound URI
        Uri soundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);

        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, EmptyActivity.class);
        notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);

        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, notificationIntent, 0);
        final DateTime dateTime = DateTime.now();
        int color = 0xffffaa00;
//        int color1 = context.getColor(R.color.notificatinBackgroundColor);
        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context);
        builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.festi_push_message_small);
        builder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
        builder.setContentTitle("Notification Sample");
        builder.setAutoCancel(true);
        builder.setContentText(message + ", Current Time : " + dateTime.getHourOfDay() + ":" + dateTime.getMinuteOfHour() + ":" + dateTime.getSecondOfMinute());
        builder.setSound(soundUri);
        builder.setLights(Color.RED, 1000, 1000);
        builder.setColor(color);


        Notification notification = builder.build();

        notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;

        notificationManager.notify(102938, notification);
    }

}
```

TimeZoneChangedReceiver:

```
public class TimeZoneChangedReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    public static String NOTIFICATION_MESSAGE = "notificationMessage";

    public static int NOW_NOTIFICATION = 101;

    Context context;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        this.context = context;
        Intent intentNitification = new Intent(context, NotificationReceiver.class);
        intentNitification.putExtra(NotificationReceiver.NOTIFICATION_MESSAGE, "Sample Alert");
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
                context, NOW_NOTIFICATION, intentNitification, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

        cancelNotification(NOW_NOTIFICATION);
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis()
                + (2 * 1000), pendingIntent);
    }

    public void cancelNotification(int requestCode) {
        try {
            Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, NotificationReceiver.class);
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, requestCode, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
            AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
            alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

AndroidManifiest:

```
<receiver android:name=".NotificationReceiver" />

        <receiver android:name=".TimeZoneChangedReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.TIMEZONE_CHANGED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```